# Klein function, modular functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I have been self studying Apostol's *Dirichlet Series and Modular Forms* and I am stuck on Theorem 2.8 on page 40.

It says it is clear that every rational function of J is a modular function.

I don't know how to prove the second part of definition of modular functions, i.e., that $f(A\tau )  = f(\tau)$  for all $A$ in modular group $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $J(A\tau)=J(\tau)$ for all $A\in\Gamma$ since $J$ is modular. Now, a rational function on $J$ is just a quotient of the form
$$F(\tau)=\frac{\sum_na_nJ(\tau)^n}{\sum_mb_mJ(\tau)^m}$$
so
$$F(A\tau)=\frac{\sum_na_nJ(A\tau)^n}{\sum_mb_mJ(A\tau)^m}
=\frac{\sum_na_nJ(\tau)^n}{\sum_mb_mJ(\tau)^m}=F(\tau)$$

Comment: Thank you very much!